# How to show only patients who "cancelled" or "no showed", but did not have a future appointment scheduled with this physician?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports to write a report that looks for patients that have "cancelled or "no showed" for an appointment with a specific physician in the past seven days. Then I need to see if those patients are scheduled for an appointment in the future with the same physician.  If not, I need to display their information for follow up.  I have written two reports: one to show patients who "cancelled" or "no showed" in the past 7 days

```
{TABLE.NAME} in ["Canceled", "No Show"] and
{TABLE.SPECIALTY} = "Cardiology" and
{TABLE.ES_AUDIT_TIME} in CurrentDate to CurrentDate - 7 and
{TABLE.PROV_NAME} = "Physician Name"
```

and one to determine if there are any future appointment schedule for that patient

```
{TABLE.NAME} in ["Scheduled"] and
{TABLE.SPECIALTY} = "Cardiology" and
{TABLE.PROV_NAME} = "Physician Name"
```

However, I am not sure how to combine the two to show only the patients who "cancelled" or "no showed", but did not have a future appointment scheduled with this physician.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can do it by using subreport with odbc connection.

Comment: Take new report and add these existing reports as sub reports and show

Comment: as suggested by siva use subreport to show next appointment